Flatten subdirectories of output files in Quarto
I have a Quarto project that I set up in RStudio. Quarto (v1.5.43) has been installed separately and RStudio is connected to this.
The current folder structure of the project is is:
project_folder
│   └── R
|       └── notebooks
|             └──notebook.qmd
├── _quarto.yml
|
├── project.Rproj
...

My _quarto.yml contains:
project:
   execute-dir: project
   output-dir: _output

When I render my notebook through "Render" in RStudio, the _output folder gets created in the project folder, containing the rendered notebook (HTML or PDF), but this rendered document (and execution files) is nested in the subdirectory structure that reflects the structure of the original notebook.qmd.
To illustrate:
project_folder
│   └── R
|       └── notebooks
|             └──notebook.qmd
├── _quarto.yml
|
├── project.Rproj
|
├── _output
|      └── R
|          └── notebooks
|                ├── notebook.html
|                └── notebook_files
...

I would like notebook.html (or notebook.pdf) and accompanying files to be rendered directly in _output.
One solution I tried was to place _quarto.yml in notebooks, which works, but this causes path issues with dependent R scripts that the notebook relies on.
I've struggled with finding a solution, so any suggestions are welcome!

You could use a post ender project script for copying or moving output files.
When using "Build > Render Project" in RStudio or quarto render from command line, post render script can get output dir & and a list of rendered documents though QUARTO_PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR and QUARTO_PROJECT_OUTPUT_FILES evironment variables.
Project structure
.
├── quoarto_proj.Rproj
├── R
│   └── notebooks
│       └── notebook.qmd
├── _post-copy.R
└── _quarto.yml

_quarto.yml with post-render
html + pdf to generate reports with and without extra files
project:
  execute-dir: project
  output-dir: _output
  post-render:
    - _post-copy.R
format: 
  html: default
  pdf: default


_post-copy.R post render script
out_dir <- 
  Sys.getenv("QUARTO_PROJECT_OUTPUT_DIR") |> 
  fs::path_tidy()

out_files <- 
  strsplit(Sys.getenv("QUARTO_PROJECT_OUTPUT_FILES"), "\n")[[1]] |> 
  fs::path_tidy()

# "notebook_files" for "notebook.html"
assets <- 
  out_files |> 
  grep("\\.html$", x = _, value = TRUE) |> 
  gsub("\\.html$", "_files", x = _)
assets <- assets[fs::dir_exists(assets)]

fs::file_copy(out_files, out_dir, overwrite = TRUE)
fs::dir_copy(assets, fs::path(out_dir, fs::path_file(assets)), overwrite = TRUE)

Resulting _output/
_output/
├── notebook.html
├── notebook.pdf
├── notebook_files
│   └── libs
│       ├── bootstrap
│       │   ├── bootstrap-icons.css
│       │   ├── bootstrap-icons.woff
│       │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│       │   └── bootstrap.min.js
│       ├── clipboard
│       │   └── clipboard.min.js
│       └── quarto-html
│           ├── anchor.min.js
│           ├── popper.min.js
│           ├── quarto-syntax-highlighting.css
│           ├── quarto.js
│           ├── tippy.css
│           └── tippy.umd.min.js
└── R
    └── notebooks
        ├── notebook.html
        ├── notebook.pdf
        └── notebook_files
            └── libs
                ├── bootstrap
                │   ├── bootstrap-icons.css
                │   ├── bootstrap-icons.woff
                │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
                │   └── bootstrap.min.js
                ├── clipboard
                │   └── clipboard.min.js
                └── quarto-html
                    ├── anchor.min.js
                    ├── popper.min.js
                    ├── quarto-syntax-highlighting.css
                    ├── quarto.js
                    ├── tippy.css
                    └── tippy.umd.min.js

You can also remove _output/R or just use rename / move instead of copy.

Many thanks. I'll give this a try. Pity though that there is not a more straightforward way of defining the output path.

This is for Rmarkdown, since you tagged it, might help others searching too.
in some cases, the output_dir in the YAML doesn't output to a different location, but the command line rendering does.
rmarkdown::render("Untitled.rmd",  output_dir = "/Users/john/reporting.html")

the quarto::quarto_render() command line tool lets you specify an output FILE, but not a directory. so maybe you could issue the command to render quarto project, and then a one line command in the console to copy it to your desired destination.
file.copy(file.path("/Users/john", "report.html"), "/Users/john/Downloads/report.html")

helpful link
